# Propiedad: Mostrar/Ocultar controles dentro de un Control de Usuario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox, usercontrol

Estoy intentando crear una `Categoría` para los `controles` (componentes) dentro de un `Control de Usuario` de modo que se reflejen en las `Propiedades` del Visual Studio, para hacer visible/no visible un `PictureBox`, entre otras opciones, lo hice así:

```
    bool _pictureBoxVisible = true;
    Image _imagenPictureBox = Properties.Resources.Laimagen;
    Color _colorFondoPanel = Color.Transparent;
    Color _colorLetraLabel = Color.White;
    Font _letraLabel = new Font("Tahoma", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    [Category("Configuración Control")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [DesignOnly(true)]
    [Description("Si es Verdadero (True), se muestra. Si es Falso (False) no mostrarlo.")]
    [DisplayName("Mostrar/Ocultar")]
    public bool PictureBoxVisible
    {
        get { return _pictureBoxVisible; }
        set 
        {
            _pictureBoxVisible = value;

            if (_pictureBoxVisible)
                this.picturebox_imagen.Visible = true; 
            else
                this.picturebox_imagen.Visible = false; 
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Problemas a resolver**
>
> 1- La propiedad me sale correctamente en las propiedades del diseño, pero cuando cambio la propiedad en los dos controles en uno funciona y en otro no, y en el diseño se muestran correctamente, pero al ejecutar la aplicación se muestra el `picturebox` aunque el valor de la propiedad sea `false` **¿Cómo lo resuelvo?**

**Además quisiera exponer en la misma categoría las siguientes propiedades:**

- 2: Desplazar el PictureBox hasta la esquina lateral derecha del panel, cuando el panel cambia su `Resize`.
- 3: El color de Fondo del Panel (BackColor)
- 4: Color de la Letra del Label (ForeColor)
- 5: Fuente del Label (Font)
- 6: La imagen y/o BackgroundImage del PictureBox

Pero no se como exponer esas otras propiedades para que me salgan así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **¿Cómo accedo a crear esas propiedades del sistema?**

Entorno: Visual Studio & .NET Netframework 4

Comment: No he trabajado antes con propiedades de este modo, con lo que he haz enviado pude resolver el primer punto que se muestra en la imagen , removiendo esto: `[DefaultValue(true)]` y `[DesignOnly(true)]` , pero **no se** como hacer las demás propiedades, ¿Puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Ah ok.. eso es un problema mas complejo.. vos queres que salga el colorpicker por ejemplo.. si lo quisiera hacer tambien deberia googlearlo, porque de memoria no me lo acuerd... ;)

Comment: No tenes que dockearlo al borde que queres? No recuerdo como se hacia en winforms

Comment: No actualices la pregunta. pon todo lo que estas encontrando como respuesta!

Comment: @gbianchi Listo!. Ya he realizado todo lo que necesitaba, publiqué la respuesta, al final no fue tan difícil, inventando un poco lo logré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Al final lo he logrado. Gracias [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) por ayudarme a resolver los puntos `1` y `2`

**Puntos resueltos:**

Punto 1 : Quitando esto: `[DefaultValue(true)]` y `[DesignOnly(true)]`

Punto 2 : Cambiando la **Propiedad** `Dock` a `Right`.

Punto 3 : Color Fondo Panel:

```
    Color _color_fondo_panel = Color.Transparent;

    [Category("Panel Plegable")]
    [Description("Color de Fondo del Panel.")]
    [DisplayName("Color Fondo Panel")]
    public Color ColorFondoPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return _color_fondo_panel;
        }
        set
        {
            _color_fondo_panel = value;
            panel_titulo.BackColor = _color_fondo_panel;
        }
    }
```

Punto 4 : Color Letra Label:

```
Color _color_titulo_menu = Color.Black;

[Category("Panel Plegable")]
[Description("Color del Título del Menú.")]
[DisplayName("Color Título Menú")]
public Color ColorTituloMenu
{
     get
     {
        return _color_titulo_menu;
     }
     set
     {
        _color_titulo_menu = value;
        label_titulo.ForeColor = _color_titulo_menu;
     }
}
```

Punto 5 : Fuente del Label:

```
    Font _fuente_titulo_menu = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    [Category("Panel Plegable")]
    [Description("Fuente del Título del Menú.")]
    [DisplayName("Fuente Título Menú")]
    public Font FuenteTituloMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return _fuente_titulo_menu;
        }
        set
        {
            _fuente_titulo_menu = value;
            label_titulo.Font = _fuente_titulo_menu;
        }
    }
```

Punto 6 : Imagen Fondo PictureBox:

```
    Image _imagen_categoria_menu = Properties.Resources.Myimagen;

    [Category("Panel Plegable")]
    [Description("Imagen de Fondo Categoría Menu.")]
    [DisplayName("Imagen Categoría Menú")]
    public Image ImagenCategoriaMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return _imagen_categoria_menu;
        }
        set
        {
            _imagen_categoria_menu = value;
            pictureBox_imagen_categoria.BackgroundImage = _imagen_categoria_menu;
        }
    }
```

**Resultado Final:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]